# ColdFusion regex to wrap certain content with classed span

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to achieve what looks like not too complicated task with no results so far.

Here's a sample string:

```
<cfset myString = "cm: first_part; fn: second_part; There was a farmer who had a dog">
```

The required output should be:

```
"cm: <span class='highlight'>first_part</span>; fn: <span class='highlight'>second_part</span>; There was a farmer who had a dog"
```

How one would go about it? The notes/restrictions is that it has to be done in ColdFusion 10 (I would suspect using Regex).

So far what I've got so far is this:

```
<cfoutput>#ReReplace(myString,"(cm:)?:(.*?);","<span class='highlight'>"&REMatch("(cm:)?:(.*?);",myString)[1]&"</span>","one")#</cfoutput>
```

This of course only changes the first part between cm and the following ';'

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: `first_part` is anything between (exactly) `cm: ` and `; fn:`, and `second_part` is anything between (exactly) `fn: ` and... what... the *next* semicolon? Or the *last* semicolon? IE: can `second_part` contain semicolons? Can the `[rest of string]` contain semicolons?

Comment: Just not to leave this unanswered, the second_part would not contain semicolons. The rest of the text may. Also the second_part is between 'fn:' and the next semicolon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional on the answer to my questions above, replacing `^(cm: )(.*)(; fn: )(.*)(; .*?)$` with `\1<span class='highlight'>\2</span>\3<span class='highlight'>\4</span>\5` might work.

This will not handle semicolons in `second_part` correctly.

Comment: Adding a single question mark seemed to solve it completely. The final line:
<cfoutput>#REReplace(myString, "^(cm: )(.*)(; fn: )(.*?)(;.*?)$","\1<span class='highlight'>\2</span>\3<span class='highlight'>\4</span>\5")#</cfoutput>

Comment: In general, you should try to avoid `.*` and `.*?` - there is nearly always something more specific that can be used that will give better performance - in this case `[^;]*` will consume only the text needed then move on (whilst `.*` consumes the rest of the string then backtracks).

Comment: Also, having a lazy match followed by an end of string anchor is redundant - i.e. `.*?$` cannot match differently to `.*$` _(except in multiline mode, which is not enabled here)_ but the different behaviour of lazy matching vs greedy will impact the performance (unless the regex engine optimises it, but I don't think CF/Java ones will).

Comment: Yep, thanks Peter. I don't think on a string of the length we're talking about it's worth micro-optimising stuff at the expense of code clarity. Also, as I said... "conditional on the answers...". It was a general answer until I got clarification. At the time I answered, I did not know whether there would be other semi-colons to deal with. Sometimes a less-focused pattern is a better fit so as to not have to revisit for unexpected assumptions.

Comment: But, yeah, sorry... I *thought* I had removed the `?`. I certainly have here in regex coach!?!

Comment: Well it's not _necessarily_ micro-optimising if the regex is nested in large nested loops - stuff like this can sometimes make non-trivial impacts on speed. (But yeah, that really only matters when there is an identified performance issue). However, I would argue that it's more clear to have something like `[^;]` than `.` (obviously pending it being acceptable) because it's describing what is actually expected for future readers of the code.

Comment: Too often I've been bitten on the bum by having an nicely-tuned pattern which then unexpected breaks because edgecases of the pattern were not identified, eg "oh, no, it'll *never* have semi-colons in there"... except when it does. I've never had a case where a *regex* operation has been the source of a performance hit, whereas I *have* had them fail as per above. I contend your advice is *theoretically* bang-on; but in the real world: I'm not so sure. It's def worth being aware of though.

Comment: (NB: amusingly... I *knew* you'd pick me up on this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do both parts with a single expression like this:

```
rereplace
    ( myString
    , "(cm: |fn: )([^;]*)(?=;)"
    , "\1<span class='highlight'>\2</span>"
    , "all"
    )
```

It can be slightly simplified by using Java's replaceAll method, where lookbehind can be used to avoid the need for capturing groups:

```
myString.replaceAll
    ( "(?<=cm: |fn: )[^;]*(?=;)"
    , "<span class='highlight'>$0</span>"
    )
```

Whether matching individually like this is better than matching as part of the entire text  (as per Adam's answer) will depend on the use case - i.e. how representative the sample string is to the real inputs, and what is expected to occur if there happens to be multiple cm/fn sections.

Comment: Thanks Peter, both yours and Adam's answers are working well. Unfortunately I'm not able to select two correct answers, so since Adam provided his first, I'll have to leave the green tick on his. Up voted yours though. Again, thanks!